# Understanding ARC in iOS

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, grand-central-dispatch, weak-references

I have this block of code I have written to test ARC. I set the string s2 as weak and assign it the value of s1. Then, I set s1 to nil. I was assuming that since this background block is executed at a later time, s2 will already be dealloced by then. But, when I run this code, the NSLog still prints the value of s2 as "123". Can someone please explain to me why that happens?

```
- (void)testARC {
    NSString *s1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"123"];
    __weak NSString *s2 = s1;
    s1 = nil;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
        // what will NSLog print?
        NSLog(@"s2 = %@", s2);
    });
}
```

Comment: The memory for @"123" is deallocated when its reference count becomes zero, not when the last strong pointer is set to nil. The system decides when to decrement the reference count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two considerations:

1. You're creating an autorelease object which isn't released until the pool is drained. If you create a non-autorelease object (or use your own autorelease pool), you won't see that behavior, e.g.:

   ```
   NSString *s1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"123"];
   __weak NSString *s2 = s1;
   s1 = nil;
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
       // what will NSLog print?
       NSLog(@"s2 = %@", s2);
   });
   ```
2. You always should be wary of evaluating memory behavior using `NSString`. In this case, I don't think it matters, but in other cases `NSString` will do all sorts of optimizations and caching that can affect the behavior. I'd suggest testing this with `NSObject` or an `NSObject` subclass.